# How to parse and pass data to my Morris.js chart

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-blade, morris.js

I want to use morris charts in my application to display some data. First, let me show you my js:

```
var handleStoreIncomeShareDonutChart = function() {
    var green = '#00acac';
    var blue = '#348fe2';

    Morris.Donut({
        element: 'storeincomeshare-donut-chart',
        data: [
            {label: "Store 1", value: 69},
            {label: "Store 2", value: 31}
        ],
        colors: [green, blue],
        labelFamily: 'Open Sans',
        labelColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.4)',
        labelTextSize: '12px',
        backgroundColor: '#242a30'
    });
};
```

This is a snippet in my charts.js file.  This code works. But now I want to add data from my database.

I have seen different approaches on this, but nothing seems to work for me. the dd'ed data looks like this:

```
array:2 [▼
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Store 1"
    "value" => 25
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "name" => "Store 2"
    "value" => 75
  ]
```

]

How do I need to parse this data? And how can I attach it to my chart, because I can't do blade syntax style/php in js files.

Thanks,
LuMa

---

## EDIT

I have an update! Your answer helped me a lot, but I still habe a small problem. I know the problem, but can't tell why it happens.

Let's take this sample data:

```
$data = [
    [
        "label" => "Store 1",
        "value" => "75"
    ],
    [
        "label" => "Store 2",
        "value" => "25"
    ],
];
```

DD'ed wit will look like this:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "label" => "Store 1"
    "value" => "75"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "label" => "Store 2"
    "value" => "25"
  ]
]
```

Doing `json_encode($data)` and dd the result will look like this:
`"[{"label":"Store 1","value":"75"},{"label":"Store 2","value":"25"}]"`
or formated:

```
[
    {
    "label": "Store 1",
    "value": "75"
},
{
    "label": "Store 2",
    "value": "25"
}
```

]

This is valid JSON and works with the morris.js chart. But there is something interesting when I do the same with my data from db.

DD'ed it will look like this:

```
array:2 [▼
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "label" => "Store 1"
    "value" => 75
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "label" => "Store 2"
    "value" => 25
  ]
]
```

And `json_encode()` will NOT encode it the way it did above:

```
{
    "1": {
        "label": "Studio Friedberg",
        "value": 0
    },
    "2": {
        "label": "Studio Klein-Auheim",
        "value": 0
    }
}
```

This is also valid JSON, but not accepted by the morris.js chart.
It took me some time to figure it out, why this happens. You can't spot the difference so good, so let's take a look at these two pictures:

[image: The array with some sample data I added]
[image: The array with data from my database]

So what was my problem? I had a foreach loop in which I set the array key to the id of the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert it to the correct format with an array_map, and output it as a variable in a `<script>` before loading your `handleStoreIncomeShareDonutChart` file. The following code should work in PHP 5.3 and above.

```php
$data = array(
  array(
    'name' => 'Store 1',
    'value' => 25,
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'Store 2',
    'value' => 75,
  ),
);

$output = array_map(function ($record) {
  return array(
    'label' => $record['name'],
    'value' => $record['value'],
  );
}, $data);
echo '<script>var morris_data = ' . json_encode($output) . ';';
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Yes, this idea is great. But I struggle with one thing: http://laravel.io/bin/zjj9d The chart doesn't render with this data, but I don't know why,

Comment: Don't quote the data coming out of json_encode(). Right now you're making it a string, but you want it to be an object.

Comment: Yes, thanks for that. You solved the problem. But I made a big edit to the question because I found out something interesting. You might take look.