# Populating charts via JS

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, bootstrap-4

I'm developing an application with Laravel 8.

For the needs of the application I have chosen a bootstrap template containing graphics and which I have to populate based on the data obtained from my queries.
In the template I have a sample morris-init.js file but I don't understand how to use it to populate my chart on the page where I need it.

Can anyone help me understand how to use the example file? I tried to copy it to the page where I need it but I get nothing.

Here my code:

- js example file:

```
(function($) {
    "use strict"

    var dzMorris = function(){
        
        var screenWidth = $(window).width();
        
        var setChartWidth = function(){
            if(screenWidth <= 768)
            {
                var chartBlockWidth = 0;
                chartBlockWidth = (screenWidth < 300 )?screenWidth:300;
                jQuery('.morris_chart_height').css('min-width',chartBlockWidth - 31);
            }
        }
        
        var donutChart = function(){
            Morris.Donut({
                element: 'morris_donught',
                data: [{
                    label: "\xa0 \xa0 Download Sales \xa0 \xa0",
                    value: 12,

                }, {
                    label: "\xa0 \xa0 In-Store Sales \xa0 \xa0",
                    value: 30
                }, {
                    label: "\xa0 \xa0 Mail-Order Sales \xa0 \xa0",
                    value: 20
                }],
                resize: true,
                redraw: true,
                colors: ['#3a7afe', 'rgb(255, 159, 0)', '#10ca93'],
                //responsive:true,
                
            });
        }
        
        var lineChart = function(){
            //line chart
            let line = new Morris.Line({
                element: 'morris_line',
                resize: true,
                data: [{
                        y: '2011 Q1',
                        item1: 2666
                    },
                    {
                        y: '2011 Q2',
                        item1: 2778
                    },
                    {
                        y: '2011 Q3',
                        item1: 4912
                    },
                    {
                        y: '2011 Q4',
                        item1: 3767
                    },
                    {
                        y: '2012 Q1',
                        item1: 6810
                    },
                    {
                        y: '2012 Q2',
                        item1: 5670
                    },
                    {
                        y: '2012 Q3',
                        item1: 4820
                    },
                    {
                        y: '2012 Q4',
                        item1: 15073
                    },
                    {
                        y: '2013 Q1',
                        item1: 10687
                    },
                    {
                        y: '2013 Q2',
                        item1: 8432
                    }
                ],
                xkey: 'y',
                ykeys: ['item1'],
                labels: ['Item 1'],
                gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                lineColors: ['rgb(58, 122, 254)'], //here
                lineWidth: 1,
                hideHover: 'auto',
                pointSize: 0,
                axes: false
            }); 
        }
        
        var lineChart2 = function(){
            //Area chart
            Morris.Area({
                element: 'line_chart_2',
                data: [{
                        period: '2001',
                        smartphone: 0,
                        windows: 0,
                        mac: 0
                    }, {
                        period: '2002',
                        smartphone: 90,
                        windows: 60,
                        mac: 25
                    }, {
                        period: '2003',
                        smartphone: 40,
                        windows: 80,
                        mac: 35
                    }, {
                        period: '2004',
                        smartphone: 30,
                        windows: 47,
                        mac: 17
                    }, {
                        period: '2005',
                        smartphone: 150,
                        windows: 40,
                        mac: 120
                    }, {
                        period: '2006',
                        smartphone: 25,
                        windows: 80,
                        mac: 40
                    }, {
                        period: '2007',
                        smartphone: 10,
                        windows: 10,
                        mac: 10
                    }


                ],
                xkey: 'period',
                ykeys: ['smartphone', 'windows', 'mac'],
                labels: ['Phone', 'Windows', 'Mac'],
                pointSize: 3,
                fillOpacity: 0,
                pointStrokeColors: ['#f25767', '#10ca93', '#3a7afe'],
                behaveLikeLine: true,
                gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                lineWidth: 3,
                hideHover: 'auto',
                lineColors: ['rgb(242, 87, 103)', 'rgb(0, 171, 197)', '#3a7afe'],
                resize: true

            });
        }
        
        var barChart = function(){
            //bar chart
            Morris.Bar({
                element: 'morris_bar',
                data: [{
                    y: '2006',
                    a: 100,
                    b: 90,
                    c: 60
                }, {
                    y: '2007',
                    a: 75,
                    b: 65,
                    c: 40
                }, {
                    y: '2008',
                    a: 50,
                    b: 40,
                    c: 30
                }, {
                    y: '2009',
                    a: 75,
                    b: 65,
                    c: 40
                }, {
                    y: '2010',
                    a: 50,
                    b: 40,
                    c: 30
                }, {
                    y: '2011',
                    a: 75,
                    b: 65,
                    c: 40
                }, {
                    y: '2012',
                    a: 100,
                    b: 90,
                    c: 40
                }],
                xkey: 'y',
                ykeys: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                labels: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                barColors: ['#3a7afe', '#10ca93', '#ff9f00'],
                hideHover: 'auto',
                gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                resize: true,
                barSizeRatio: 0.25,
            }); 
        }
        
        var barStalkChart = function(){
            //bar chart
            Morris.Bar({
                element: 'morris_bar_stalked',
                data: [{
                    y: 'S',
                    a: 66, 
                    b: 34
                }, {
                    y: 'M',
                    a: 75, 
                    b: 25
                }, {
                    y: 'T',
                    a: 50, 
                    b: 50
                }, {
                    y: 'W',
                    a: 75, 
                    b: 25
                }, {
                    y: 'T',
                    a: 50, 
                    b: 50
                }, {
                    y: 'F',
                    a: 16, 
                    b: 84
                }, {
                    y: 'S',
                    a: 70, 
                    b: 30
                }, {
                    y: 'S',
                    a: 30, 
                    b: 70
                }, {
                    y: 'M',
                    a: 40, 
                    b: 60
                }, {
                    y: 'T',
                    a: 29, 
                    b: 71
                }, {
                    y: 'W',
                    a: 44, 
                    b: 56
                }, {
                    y: 'T',
                    a: 30, 
                    b: 70
                }, {
                    y: 'F',
                    a: 60, 
                    b: 40
                }, {
                    y: 'G',
                    a: 40, 
                    b: 60
                }, {
                    y: 'S',
                    a: 46, 
                    b: 54
                }],
                xkey: 'y',
                ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
                labels: ['A', 'B'],
                barColors: ['#3a7afe', "#F1F3F7"],
                hideHover: 'auto',
                gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                resize: true,
                barSizeRatio: 0.25,
                stacked: true, 
                behaveLikeLine: true,
                //redraw: true
                
                // barRadius: [6, 6, 0, 0]
            });
        
        }
        
        var areaChart = function(){
            //area chart
            Morris.Area({
                element: 'morris_area',
                data: [{
                        period: '2001',
                        smartphone: 0,
                        windows: 0,
                        mac: 0
                    }, {
                        period: '2002',
                        smartphone: 90,
                        windows: 60,
                        mac: 25
                    }, {
                        period: '2003',
                        smartphone: 40,
                        windows: 80,
                        mac: 35
                    }, {
                        period: '2004',
                        smartphone: 30,
                        windows: 47,
                        mac: 17
                    }, {
                        period: '2005',
                        smartphone: 150,
                        windows: 40,
                        mac: 120
                    }, {
                        period: '2006',
                        smartphone: 25,
                        windows: 80,
                        mac: 40
                    }, {
                        period: '2007',
                        smartphone: 10,
                        windows: 10,
                        mac: 10
                    }


                ],
                lineColors: ['#3a7afe', 'rgb(16, 202, 147)', 'rgb(255, 159, 0)'],
                xkey: 'period',
                ykeys: ['smartphone', 'windows', 'mac'],
                labels: ['Phone', 'Windows', 'Mac'],
                pointSize: 0,
                lineWidth: 0,
                resize: true,
                fillOpacity: 0.95,
                behaveLikeLine: true,
                gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                hideHover: 'auto'

            });
        }
        
        var areaChart2 = function(){
            //area chart
            Morris.Area({
                element: 'morris_area_2',
                data: [{
                        period: '2010',
                        SiteA: 0,
                        SiteB: 0,

                    }, {
                        period: '2011',
                        SiteA: 130,
                        SiteB: 100,

                    }, {
                        period: '2012',
                        SiteA: 80,
                        SiteB: 60,

                    }, {
                        period: '2013',
                        SiteA: 70,
                        SiteB: 200,

                    }, {
                        period: '2014',
                        SiteA: 180,
                        SiteB: 150,

                    }, {
                        period: '2015',
                        SiteA: 105,
                        SiteB: 90,

                    },
                    {
                        period: '2016',
                        SiteA: 250,
                        SiteB: 150,

                    }
                ],
                xkey: 'period',
                ykeys: ['SiteA', 'SiteB'],
                labels: ['Site A', 'Site B'],
                pointSize: 0,
                fillOpacity: 0.6,
                pointStrokeColors: ['#b4becb', '#00A2FF'], //here
                behaveLikeLine: true,
                gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                lineWidth: 0,
                smooth: false,
                hideHover: 'auto',
                lineColors: ['rgb(0, 171, 197)', 'rgb(0, 0, 128)'],
                resize: true

            }); 
        }
        
        
        /* Function ============ */
        return {
            init:function(){
            },
            
            
            load:function(){
                setChartWidth();
                donutChart();
                lineChart();
                lineChart2();
                barChart();
                barStalkChart();
                areaChart();
                areaChart2();
            },
            
            resize:function(){
                screenWidth = $(window).width();
                setChartWidth();
                donutChart();
                lineChart();
                lineChart2();
                barChart();
                barStalkChart();
                areaChart();
                areaChart2();
            }
        }
        
    }();

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    });
        
    jQuery(window).on('load',function(){
        dzMorris.load();
    });

    jQuery(window).on('resize',function(){
        dzMorris.resize();
        
    });
   
})(jQuery);
```

my view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="card-title">Report residui per fasce</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-responsive-md" style="min-width: 845px">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Fascia</th>
                    <th># Posizioni</th>
                    <th>Residuo &euro;</th>
                    <th>% Posizioni</th>
                    <th>% Residuo</th>
                    <th>Valore Medio &euro;</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  @if(!empty($fascia1))
                    <tr>
                      <td><span class="badge light badge-lg badge-info"> < 100 &euro;</span></td>
                      <td>{{ $fascia1[0]['total'] }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $fascia1[0]['residuo'] }} &euro;</td>
                      <td>{{ (100*$fascia1[0]['total'])/$tot_posizioni}} % </td>
                      <td>{{ (100*$fascia1[0]['residuo'])/$tot_residuo}} %</td>
                      <td>{{ round($fascia1[0]['residuo']/$fascia1[0]['total'], 2) }} &euro;</td>
                    </tr>
                  @else
                  <tr>
                    <td><span class="badge light badge-lg badge-info"> < 100 &euro;</span> </td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0 &euro;</td>
                    <td>0 % </td>
                    <td>0 %</td>
                    <td>0 &euro;</td>
                  </tr>
                  @endif
                  @if(!empty($fascia2))
                    <tr>
                      <td><span class="badge light badge-lg badge-success">100 - 1000 &euro;</span></td>
                      <td>{{ $fascia2[0]['total'] }}</td>
                      <td>{{ $fascia2[0]['residuo'] }} &euro;</td>
                      <td>{{ (100*$fascia2[0]['total'])/$tot_posizioni}} % </td>
                      <td>{{ (100*$fascia2[0]['residuo'])/$tot_residuo}} %</td>
                      <td>{{ round($fascia2[0]['residuo']/$fascia2[0]['total'], 2) }} &euro;</td>
                    </tr>
                  @else
                    <tr>
                      <td><span class="badge light badge-lg badge-success"> 100 - 1000 &euro;</span></td>
                      <td>0</td>
                      <td>0 &euro;</td>
                      <td>0 % </td>
                      <td>0 %</td>
                      <td>0 &euro;</td>
                    </tr>
                  @endif
                  @if(!empty($fascia3)) 
                  <tr>
                    <td><span class="badge light badge-lg badge-light">1000 - 5000 &euro;</span></td>
                    <td>{{ $fascia3[0]['total'] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $fascia3[0]['residuo'] }} &euro;</td>
                    <td>{{ (100*$fascia3[0]['total'])/$tot_posizioni}} % </td>
                    <td>{{ (100*$fascia3[0]['residuo'])/$tot_residuo}} %</td>
                    <td>{{ round($fascia3[0]['residuo']/$fascia3[0]['total'], 2) }} &euro;</td>
                  </tr>
                  @else
                  <tr>
                    <td><span class="badge light badge-lg badge-light"> 1000 - 5000 &euro;</span></td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0 &euro;</td>
                    <td>0 % </td>
                    <td>0 %</td>
                    <td>0 &euro;</td>
                  </tr>
                  @endif
                  @if(!empty($fascia4))
                  <tr>
                    <td><span class="badge light badge-lg badge-dark">5000 - 10000 &euro;</span></td>
                    <td>{{ $fascia4[0]['total'] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $fascia4[0]['residuo'] }} &euro;</td>
                    <td>{{ (100*$fascia4[0]['total'])/$tot_posizioni}} % </td>
                    <td>{{ (100*$fascia4[0]['residuo'])/$tot_residuo}} %</td>
                    <td>{{ round($fascia4[0]['residuo']/$fascia4[0]['total'], 2) }} &euro;</td>
                  </tr>
                  @else
                  <tr>
                    <td><span class="badge light badge-lg badge-dark"> 5000 - 10000 &euro;</span> </td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0 &euro;</td>
                    <td>0 % </td>
                    <td>0 %</td>
                    <td>0 &euro;</td>
                  </tr>
                  @endif
                  @if(!empty($fascia5))
                  <tr>
                    <td><span class="badge light badge-lg badge-warning">10000 - 20000 &euro;</span></td>
                    <td>{{ $fascia5[0]['total'] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $fascia5[0]['residuo'] }} &euro;</td>
                    <td>{{ (100*$fascia5[0]['total'])/$tot_posizioni}} % </td>
                    <td>{{ (100*$fascia5[0]['residuo'])/$tot_residuo}} %</td>
                    <td>{{ round($fascia5[0]['residuo']/$fascia5[0]['total'], 2) }} &euro;</td>
                  </tr>
                  @else
                  <tr>
                    <td><span class="badge light badge-lg badge-warning"> 10000 - 20000 &euro; </span></td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0 &euro;</td>
                    <td>0 % </td>
                    <td>0 %</td>
                    <td>0 &euro;</td>
                  </tr>
                  @endif
                  @if(!empty($fascia6))
                  <tr>
                    <td><span class="badge light badge-lg badge-danger"> > 2000 &euro;</span></td>
                    <td>{{ $fascia6[0]['total'] }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $fascia6[0]['residuo'] }} &euro;</td>
                    <td>{{ (100*$fascia6[0]['total'])/$tot_posizioni}} % </td>
                    <td>{{ (100*$fascia6[0]['residuo'])/$tot_residuo}} %</td>
                    <td>{{ round($fascia6[0]['residuo']/$fascia6[0]['total'], 2) }} &euro;</td>
                  </tr>
                  @else
                  <tr>
                    <td><span class="badge light badge-lg badge-danger"> > 20000 &euro;</span> </td>
                    <td>0</td>
                    <td>0 &euro;</td>
                    <td>0 % </td>
                    <td>0 %</td>
                    <td>0 &euro;</td>
                  </tr>
                  @endif
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                  <th></th>
                  <th>Tot posizioni: {{ $tot_posizioni}}</th>
                  <th>Tot residuo: {{ $tot_residuo}} &euro;</th>
                  <th>100%</th>
                  <th>100%</th>
                  <th>Tot medio: {{ round($tot_residuo/$tot_posizioni, 2) }} &euro;</th>
                </tfoot>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- grafichiamo i risultati stampati in tabella -->
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4 class="card-title">Residui per fasce</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="morris_donught" class="morris_chart_height"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    //here i've copied the js example code ( I NEED ONLY donutChart )
(function($) {
    "use strict"

    var dzMorris = function(){
        
        var screenWidth = $(window).width();
        
        var setChartWidth = function(){
            if(screenWidth <= 768)
            {
                var chartBlockWidth = 0;
                chartBlockWidth = (screenWidth < 300 )?screenWidth:300;
                jQuery('.morris_chart_height').css('min-width',chartBlockWidth - 31);
            }
        }
        
        var donutChart = function(){
            Morris.Donut({
                element: 'morris_donught',
                data: [{
                    label: "\xa0 \xa0 Download Sales \xa0 \xa0",
                    value: 12,

                }, {
                    label: "\xa0 \xa0 In-Store Sales \xa0 \xa0",
                    value: 30
                }, {
                    label: "\xa0 \xa0 Mail-Order Sales \xa0 \xa0",
                    value: 20
                }],
                resize: true,
                redraw: true,
                colors: ['#3a7afe', 'rgb(255, 159, 0)', '#10ca93'],
                //responsive:true,
                
            });
        }
        
        var lineChart = function(){
            //line chart
            let line = new Morris.Line({
                element: 'morris_line',
                resize: true,
                data: [{
                        y: '2011 Q1',
                        item1: 2666
                    },
                    {
                        y: '2011 Q2',
                        item1: 2778
                    },
                    {
                        y: '2011 Q3',
                        item1: 4912
                    },
                    {
                        y: '2011 Q4',
                        item1: 3767
                    },
                    {
                        y: '2012 Q1',
                        item1: 6810
                    },
                    {
                        y: '2012 Q2',
                        item1: 5670
                    },
                    {
                        y: '2012 Q3',
                        item1: 4820
                    },
                    {
                        y: '2012 Q4',
                        item1: 15073
                    },
                    {
                        y: '2013 Q1',
                        item1: 10687
                    },
                    {
                        y: '2013 Q2',
                        item1: 8432
                    }
                ],
                xkey: 'y',
                ykeys: ['item1'],
                labels: ['Item 1'],
                gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                lineColors: ['rgb(58, 122, 254)'], //here
                lineWidth: 1,
                hideHover: 'auto',
                pointSize: 0,
                axes: false
            }); 
        }
        
        var lineChart2 = function(){
            //Area chart
            Morris.Area({
                element: 'line_chart_2',
                data: [{
                        period: '2001',
                        smartphone: 0,
                        windows: 0,
                        mac: 0
                    }, {
                        period: '2002',
                        smartphone: 90,
                        windows: 60,
                        mac: 25
                    }, {
                        period: '2003',
                        smartphone: 40,
                        windows: 80,
                        mac: 35
                    }, {
                        period: '2004',
                        smartphone: 30,
                        windows: 47,
                        mac: 17
                    }, {
                        period: '2005',
                        smartphone: 150,
                        windows: 40,
                        mac: 120
                    }, {
                        period: '2006',
                        smartphone: 25,
                        windows: 80,
                        mac: 40
                    }, {
                        period: '2007',
                        smartphone: 10,
                        windows: 10,
                        mac: 10
                    }


                ],
                xkey: 'period',
                ykeys: ['smartphone', 'windows', 'mac'],
                labels: ['Phone', 'Windows', 'Mac'],
                pointSize: 3,
                fillOpacity: 0,
                pointStrokeColors: ['#f25767', '#10ca93', '#3a7afe'],
                behaveLikeLine: true,
                gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                lineWidth: 3,
                hideHover: 'auto',
                lineColors: ['rgb(242, 87, 103)', 'rgb(0, 171, 197)', '#3a7afe'],
                resize: true

            });
        }
        
        var barChart = function(){
            //bar chart
            Morris.Bar({
                element: 'morris_bar',
                data: [{
                    y: '2006',
                    a: 100,
                    b: 90,
                    c: 60
                }, {
                    y: '2007',
                    a: 75,
                    b: 65,
                    c: 40
                }, {
                    y: '2008',
                    a: 50,
                    b: 40,
                    c: 30
                }, {
                    y: '2009',
                    a: 75,
                    b: 65,
                    c: 40
                }, {
                    y: '2010',
                    a: 50,
                    b: 40,
                    c: 30
                }, {
                    y: '2011',
                    a: 75,
                    b: 65,
                    c: 40
                }, {
                    y: '2012',
                    a: 100,
                    b: 90,
                    c: 40
                }],
                xkey: 'y',
                ykeys: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                labels: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                barColors: ['#3a7afe', '#10ca93', '#ff9f00'],
                hideHover: 'auto',
                gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                resize: true,
                barSizeRatio: 0.25,
            }); 
        }
        
        var barStalkChart = function(){
            //bar chart
            Morris.Bar({
                element: 'morris_bar_stalked',
                data: [{
                    y: 'S',
                    a: 66, 
                    b: 34
                }, {
                    y: 'M',
                    a: 75, 
                    b: 25
                }, {
                    y: 'T',
                    a: 50, 
                    b: 50
                }, {
                    y: 'W',
                    a: 75, 
                    b: 25
                }, {
                    y: 'T',
                    a: 50, 
                    b: 50
                }, {
                    y: 'F',
                    a: 16, 
                    b: 84
                }, {
                    y: 'S',
                    a: 70, 
                    b: 30
                }, {
                    y: 'S',
                    a: 30, 
                    b: 70
                }, {
                    y: 'M',
                    a: 40, 
                    b: 60
                }, {
                    y: 'T',
                    a: 29, 
                    b: 71
                }, {
                    y: 'W',
                    a: 44, 
                    b: 56
                }, {
                    y: 'T',
                    a: 30, 
                    b: 70
                }, {
                    y: 'F',
                    a: 60, 
                    b: 40
                }, {
                    y: 'G',
                    a: 40, 
                    b: 60
                }, {
                    y: 'S',
                    a: 46, 
                    b: 54
                }],
                xkey: 'y',
                ykeys: ['a', 'b'],
                labels: ['A', 'B'],
                barColors: ['#3a7afe', "#F1F3F7"],
                hideHover: 'auto',
                gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                resize: true,
                barSizeRatio: 0.25,
                stacked: true, 
                behaveLikeLine: true,
                //redraw: true
                
                // barRadius: [6, 6, 0, 0]
            });
        
        }
        
        var areaChart = function(){
            //area chart
            Morris.Area({
                element: 'morris_area',
                data: [{
                        period: '2001',
                        smartphone: 0,
                        windows: 0,
                        mac: 0
                    }, {
                        period: '2002',
                        smartphone: 90,
                        windows: 60,
                        mac: 25
                    }, {
                        period: '2003',
                        smartphone: 40,
                        windows: 80,
                        mac: 35
                    }, {
                        period: '2004',
                        smartphone: 30,
                        windows: 47,
                        mac: 17
                    }, {
                        period: '2005',
                        smartphone: 150,
                        windows: 40,
                        mac: 120
                    }, {
                        period: '2006',
                        smartphone: 25,
                        windows: 80,
                        mac: 40
                    }, {
                        period: '2007',
                        smartphone: 10,
                        windows: 10,
                        mac: 10
                    }


                ],
                lineColors: ['#3a7afe', 'rgb(16, 202, 147)', 'rgb(255, 159, 0)'],
                xkey: 'period',
                ykeys: ['smartphone', 'windows', 'mac'],
                labels: ['Phone', 'Windows', 'Mac'],
                pointSize: 0,
                lineWidth: 0,
                resize: true,
                fillOpacity: 0.95,
                behaveLikeLine: true,
                gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                hideHover: 'auto'

            });
        }
        
        var areaChart2 = function(){
            //area chart
            Morris.Area({
                element: 'morris_area_2',
                data: [{
                        period: '2010',
                        SiteA: 0,
                        SiteB: 0,

                    }, {
                        period: '2011',
                        SiteA: 130,
                        SiteB: 100,

                    }, {
                        period: '2012',
                        SiteA: 80,
                        SiteB: 60,

                    }, {
                        period: '2013',
                        SiteA: 70,
                        SiteB: 200,

                    }, {
                        period: '2014',
                        SiteA: 180,
                        SiteB: 150,

                    }, {
                        period: '2015',
                        SiteA: 105,
                        SiteB: 90,

                    },
                    {
                        period: '2016',
                        SiteA: 250,
                        SiteB: 150,

                    }
                ],
                xkey: 'period',
                ykeys: ['SiteA', 'SiteB'],
                labels: ['Site A', 'Site B'],
                pointSize: 0,
                fillOpacity: 0.6,
                pointStrokeColors: ['#b4becb', '#00A2FF'], //here
                behaveLikeLine: true,
                gridLineColor: 'transparent',
                lineWidth: 0,
                smooth: false,
                hideHover: 'auto',
                lineColors: ['rgb(0, 171, 197)', 'rgb(0, 0, 128)'],
                resize: true

            }); 
        }
        
        
        /* Function ============ */
        return {
            init:function(){
            },
            
            
            load:function(){
                setChartWidth();
                donutChart();
                lineChart();
                lineChart2();
                barChart();
                barStalkChart();
                areaChart();
                areaChart2();
            },
            
            resize:function(){
                screenWidth = $(window).width();
                setChartWidth();
                donutChart();
                lineChart();
                lineChart2();
                barChart();
                barStalkChart();
                areaChart();
                areaChart2();
            }
        }
        
    }();

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    });
        
    jQuery(window).on('load',function(){
        dzMorris.load();
    });

    jQuery(window).on('resize',function(){
        dzMorris.resize();
        
    });
   
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Donut, you don't need to copy the complete Self-Invoking function you just need to copy Morris. Donut code.

1- Container div on view and include cdns

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css

```
<div id="donut"></div>
```

2-Data

```
        let Data= [
            {label: "Download Sales", value: 12},
            {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
            {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
    ];
 let total = 62;
```

3- Call Morris.Donut

```
var browsersChart = Morris.Donut({
  element: 'donut',
  data: Data,
  formatter: function (value, data) { 
    return Math.floor(value/total*100) + '%'; 
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but not works, in the following answer i post my code...i think did I do something wrong

Comment: yes, i've this error: residuiReport:420 Uncaught ReferenceError: Morris is not defined
    at residuiReport:420
(anonymous) @ residuiReport:420

Comment: Did you include the cdns ?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: means code is unable to find Morris lib.Please check once

Comment: add this  var total = 62; I forget to add total variable in answer

Comment: I checked that everything is present and I did not find any errors or lack of inclusions, i don't understand why i don't take this chart

Comment: i've added this variable, but not works at all

Comment: Could you plz make a pen or fiddle so we can check together

Comment: Or try plz write jQuery on click function with alert to check all js things are present or not.

Comment: I saw that some scripts are missing and I solved it by updating the configuration cache of my laravel project, in fact now the graph is shown, but from the console I still have errors

Comment: morris.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Graph container element not found
    at c.d [as constructor] (morris.min.js:6)
    at new c (morris.min.js:6)
    at lineChart (morris-init.js:41)
    at Object.load (morris-init.js:416)
    at morris-init.js:443
    at dispatch (global.min.js:2)
    at v.handle (global.min.js:2)
and the same Uncaught Error posted in the above comments

Comment: Uncaught Error: Graph container element not found at c.d 
do you solve this?

Comment: i think this is the line on morris.min.js that create the error if(this.el="string"==typeof b.element?a(document.getElementById(b.element)):a(b.element),null==this.el||0===this.el.length)throw new Error("Graph container element not found");" but i don't now in wich way can i solve this

Comment: wrap your javascript moris code inside setTimeout((){},500) then try

Comment: I've putted into setTimeout, but nothing happens...i've tried to change timeout time but is the same..nothing happens

Comment: Did you load the scripts in the header? Please check I think Moris code is executed before div loads.

Comment: Yes, i've a configuration file that loads all my project scripts...but loads them into a footer

Answer (score 0):

- my charth code in my blade file:

```
<!-- grafichiamo i risultati stampati in tabella -->
    <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-12">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4 class="card-title">Residui per fasce</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div id="morris_donught" class="morris_chart_height">
            <div id="donut"> // this is the <div> you indicated to me
                
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

here my script at the end of the blade:

```
<script>
    //here my code
    let Data= [
        {label: "Download Sales", value: 12},
        {label: "In-Store Sales", value: 30},
        {label: "Mail-Order Sales", value: 20}
  ];
 let total = 62;
  var browsersChart = Morris.Donut({
    element: 'donut',
    data: Data,
    formatter: function (value, data) { 
      return Math.floor(value/total*100) + '%'; 
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @abhay, the graph is showed but now with the data in the script above but with the data on the example script, because i need to pass `$fascia1[0]['residuo'], $fascia2[0]['residuo'], ...` as chart data

Comment: unfortunately not, because the data that is taken to populate the graph comes from the test file I posted in the first question, and not from the script added in my blade view

Comment: If the data conversion is a problem now. Please take a look 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30514770/4129620

Comment: The problem is the fact that my chart component not use my data, passed via script at the end of the view, but use the data from the js example file